# Ember mirage route with parameters

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I have two simple routes setup in Ember mirage, one for all my sites and one for a specific id, like so:

```
  this.get('sites/:id', (db, request) => {...}
  this.get('sites/', (db, request) => {...}
```

And in my ember route I've made calls to these endpoints to populate some model properties like this:

```
model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        sites: this.store.findAll('site'),
        currentSite: this.store.queryRecord('site', { id: 1 })
    });
}
```

The chrome debugger claims it's made request to the two endpoints with the appropriate params, but if I change my method body of the `id` endpoint to console log that it's been called and the id in question, I get nothing back which suggests it's not actually being called.

I've also tried using `findRecord` to no avail.

EDIT: I switched back to `findRecord` as I couldn't remember why I'd opted for `query` in the end and noticed I get the following error:

> Error: Assertion Failed: You made a `findRecord` request for a
>   undefined with id 1, but the adapter's response did not have any data

I'm not quite sure why that is. Have I set something up wrong here?

Comment: Which mirage version are you using?

Comment: And also can you show the entire content of `this.get('sites/:id', (db, request) => {...}`? This error happens usually because mirage route returns nothing, or invalid data.

Comment: Gah, finally managed to solve it, find record did seem to call the right endpoint (but query still doesn't for me). 
I then had a stupid issue with the data type of the id param (my bad) which when changed does seem to return the right record.

Comment: Yeah, well queryRecord() sends the request on the same url as query() (in your case '/sites' ). The only difference is that queryRecord will resolve to a single object, when query resolves to a collection.

Comment: Having said that, I've got something really weird happening in my `model()` - if i call a findRecord() followed by a `findAll()` for the same model my binding for the `findAll()` doesn't work in my template, but if I comment out the `findRecord()` it does :/

Comment: @Igor ah, I didn't realise that.

Comment: I've come from .NET MVC where a request to sites/1 and sites/?id=1 would be routed to the same place

Comment: Not in ember though... Don't know whats the problem with your findAll() not working, have't had that happen to me before, and can't seem to reproduce it.

Comment: @Igor noted now! I seem to have solved the `findRecord` / `findAll` issue by putting my `findAlls` first, I can only assume it's a mirage caching issue which I'm not familiar with